# Highlight dynamic calls in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, compiler-warnings

I am writing a program in .NET with Visual Studio 2015. I have the problem that our obfuscating tool does not work when there are dynamic calls anywhere in the code, so I need to get rid of them.

Is it possible to make Visual Studio highlight the code that uses `dynamic`? Maybe give out a warning or such?

EDIT:

I do not have the word `dynamic` anywhere in my code, but there are still dynamic calls. They come from the third party API which I use. Example excerpt from the API:

```
public class ThirdPartyClass
{
    public dynamic Foo
    {
        get { ... // returns an instance of class FooClass }
    }

    ...
}
```

The class `FooClass` has a method `Bar()`.

Now let's say at some point in my code I have an instance of `ThirdPartyClass` called `tpc`. The following line of code

```
var barVar = tpc.Foo.Bar();
```

does a dynamic call, because `tpc.Foo` is dynamic. To remove the dynamic call I write instead

```
var barVar = ((FooClass)tpc.Foo).Bar();
```

This is what I need to do in order to make the obfuscation tool work again. But how do I find the dynamic calls without going through the code manually?

Comment: Do you wish to refactor the code to remove the dynamic usages?
Do you wish to know pre-compilation where the dynamic is used?
Maybe I'm over-simplifying your problem but isn't CTRL+SHIFT+F and searching for "dynamic" the solution to your problem?

Comment: You could just ctrl+F dynamic ;) Maybe there are stylecop rules forbidding the use of dynamic, you could use them.

Comment: @MichaelThePotato, @Mafii please read my updated question. Searching for the `dynamic` keyword does not help at all.

Comment: use reflection and search for all types that have methods or properties that return `dynamic` objects

Comment: @Nkosi can you explain in more detail? I have not used reflection before, so I don't know what kind of commands you might mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to find all dynamic usages in code is to temporary remove the Microsoft.CSharp dependeny. This will lead to compiler error on dynamic usage. Maybee also on other parts so you should reinclude it after removing the dynamic calls.